# Integration test for restful service using Spring MockMvc (ignoring IDs or other fields in json content response)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, integration-testing, spring-mvc-test

I've created working integration test for my application:

```
@Test
public void postCalendar() throws Exception {
    User actualUser = createUser();
    actualUser = userRepository.save(actualUser);
    String externalId = randomUUID().toString();
    Account account = new Account(actualUser, Provider.CUSTOM_PROVIDER, actualUser.getEmail(), externalId);
    accountRepository.save(account);
    Calendar expectedCalendar = createCalendarWithAccount(account);
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/calendar").contentType(V1_0)
            .content(toJSON(createCalendarDto(expectedCalendar))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(V1_0))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(notNullValue())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name", is(expectedCalendar.getName())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.title", is(expectedCalendar.getTitle())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.description", is(expectedCalendar.getDescription())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.color", is(expectedCalendar.getColor())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(expectedCalendar.getEmail())))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.primary", is(expectedCalendar.isPrimary())));
}
```

It seems works correctly now. At my first version it was not passed because of `ID` field was absent, but I would like use exactly this testing way (next test example doesn't work, it needs to ignore `id` fields):

```
@Test
public void postCalendar() throws Exception {
    User actualUser = createUser();
    actualUser = userRepository.save(actualUser);
    String externalId = randomUUID().toString();
    Account account = new Account(actualUser, Provider.CUSTOM_PROVIDER, actualUser.getEmail(), externalId);
    accountRepository.save(account);
    Calendar expectedCalendar = createCalendarWithAccount(account);
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/calendar").contentType(V1_0)
            .content(toJSON(createCalendarDto(expectedCalendar))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(V1_0))
            .andExpect(content().json(toJSON(expectedCalendar)));
}
```

If my `dto` changes - I should not care about changing test criterias, because all json would be compared.

Is it possible to fix this super test with instruction to ignore some fields (`id` for example)? How I could declare here to ignore some fields in inner objects (`id` for objects in nested collection that can be in content ofCalendar creation)?